# Differences between gel and gelatine

Tags: food-science, gelatin, gelling-agents, chemistry

Are they physically different? If so, what is the difference, between a *gel* and *gelatine*, or it's proccesses  *gelation* and *gelling* (*gelatinization*. *gelatinisation*)?

Comment: P.S: The tags [tag:gelatin] and [tag:gelling-agents] have no wiki information, so I couldn't get anything from them.

Comment: I got this doubt when first reading about starch gelatinization (or is it gelation?) in bread. And got it again when writing [this answer](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/28444/can-i-freeze-my-selfmade-focaccia/28452#comment38060_28452).

Comment: if it's an issue of definition, it sounds like a good question for the English Language and Usage site on SE! http://english.stackexchange.com

Comment: @KristinaLopez I'm meaning the physical differences. Knowing it would help me choosing the right term. Thank you for pointing it; I'll edit the question to clarity it.

Comment: Are you wondering about gelling, as in turning to gooey consistency, or jelling, as in solidifying?

Comment: @MargeGunderson: Are you meaning two different terms? [Jelly is fruit juice in/with gelatin](http://www.wordreference.com/definition/jellying). Are gel and gelatin the same thing with different consistency? If so, why is it due to?

Comment: @J.A.I.L.:I would interpret gel and gelatin as the same consistency, but I've often seen people refer to something "gelling" when they actually mean "jelling" (usually when referring to sports teams, but increasingly in other contexts). The dessert Jell-O® is named for its hardened, jelled state. From this it sounds like you do mean the gel, as in viscous and goopy?

Comment: Sorry to @J.A.I.L. and anyone else if I made this more complicated than necessary; I just see people confuse these terms so I was trying to clarify. J.A.I.L. knows what (s)he is asking. :^D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A *gel* is any liquid (usually) or gaseous medium suspended in a solid three-dimensional mesh which entraps the medium so that it does not flow.

By way of (somewhat flawed analogy) think of a giant role of bubble wrap.  Its mostly air.  But the plastic keeps the air from flowing at a large scale.

Gels can range from very soft to very hard.  New modern [aero-gels](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aerogel) have fascinating properties.

Gelatin is a protein formed when collagen (a connective protein in animals) is heated under moist conditions.  Gelatin forms cross-linked networks exceedingly well, and therefore is a wonderful gelling agent.

The name has also taken to mean the gel created from gelatin and a water-based liquid like stock or sugary flavored water. You may have guessed by now that gels in general take their name from gelatin.

So the specific answer to the first part of your question is:  gels are the general category, and gelatin (in the second sense) is a specific kind of gel.

I have never heard the term *gellification*.  The only verb I am familiar with is *to gel*.  The process is *gelatinization* or (more familiar to me), just *gelling*.

In those links in Wikipedia for [*gel*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gel), [*gelatin*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelatin), [*collagen*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collagen), and [*areogel*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aerogel) you will find out much more.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.I changed the title of the question to remove the *gellification*.

Comment: I've also seen *gelatinisation* used to refer to the denaturation of collagen. I've no idea if this is correct usage.

Comment: @SAJ14SAJ after searching some more, I've found [the propper English name for the proccess I meant is *gelation*](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=788869).

Comment: Now that you mention it, I think I have heard that....   but I am a computer scientist, not a chemist so  I stand corrected :-)

Answer (score -1):

Gelatinization means the starch grains swelling, releasing the starch molecules, which then cross link to thicken the liquid. The gel forms, trapping water between chains of starch. It is a heating process. Gelation is a cooling process as the gel sets.

Comment: Gelatine (and alternatives like agar, carrageenan ... ) is not a starch and still makes gels...